# Ubuntu 12.04 & Grub on Macbook

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, external-hdd, macbook

Several months ago I installed Ubuntu in an external 500MB USB disk (and on an old MacBook4,1).
with a GPT Partition table and partitioned as following:

- swap
- swap
- an unique ext4 partition for Ubuntu
- one NTFS partition for datas

Everything worked fine with Grub on sda (a 500MB disk with standard osx installation and partitions).

Some days ago I installed another distro in another USB disk, also with GPT:

- a couple NTFS partitions
- swap
- swap
- unformatted 12 MB flagged as bios_grub
- root
- var
- home

and installed this Grub in the external disk. Both installations does not rely on EFI to boot.

When I tried to boot the new installation a message always complained about the lack of the other partition (Ubuntu) so I did a backup and cleared the MBR.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1
```

Short story, after clearing (and also after restoring) the MBR I am not anymore able to boot Ubuntu and when trying to reinstall Grub from the LIVE CD I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/grub-setup: warn: This GPT partition label has no BIOS Boot Partition, embedding won't be possible.

/usr/bin/grub-setup: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required fro cross-disk install.
```

Well, how Grub installed originally at Ubuntu installation time? There is something different from grub-install procedure?

Both Ubuntu (I've installed a Grub also in it) and the other distro boot fine on another computer, but after reading a lot of posts here and there nothing worked for me and I am really confused:

how can I restore the Grub and let both disk to boot?

Without to say that I am afraid that trying the EFI way would produce nasty effects.

Comment: Btw, I see that the question got a -1, does not show any research effort: that's simply not true. There are days that I am reading posts here and there, without find a good solution. So, if you don't know how to answer, don't judge please.

Answer (score 1):

I did an AHT (Hardware text) extended. Looks like the internal controller is defective (4HDD/11/40000004:SATA(0:0) and after some time causes an invalid node structure.

I think the issue is raised from the controller malfunction (HD imminent failure is a consequence) and probably leads to my issue trying to install Grub:

it is not possible to install anything not to be that you reformat the hard drive, procedure that temporarily restores the functionality of the disc.

After formatting I was able to install Grub.

Long time solution: replace the controller (or the computer).

Comment: Thank you to the down voter for pointing intelligently out the root cause.